# Run InitialMigration from C# code

Tags: c#, text, entity-framework-core

How can I add and run a migration from C# code? I want to deploy my solution without the code, and it must be able to build the model from a migration in an empty database. I use EF CORE.

Basically, I want to translate the Add-Migration InitialMigration; Update-Database; from Package manager commands to c# code. (But only if the DB is empty)

Comment: Sounds like you are seeking for equivalent of EF6 automatic migrations. Sorry, they have been retired in EF Core. You can run migrations at run time, but you cannot create (add) them.

Comment: And how can i run a migration at run time ?

Comment: [Applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#applying-migrations-at-runtime)